# React Native - Redux state is updating but component view isn't updating properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

The app has the following functionality.

- A list of orders is fetched from server on home page and it's saved in Redux `orders` state.
- Orders have various statuses "Open", "In Progress", "Pending", "Completed", "Cancelled".
- In app, there is a component "Orders". It have 3 tabs in tab view. "Open", "Ongoing" and "History". Open shows "Open" orders, Ongoing shows "In progress" and "Pending" orders. History shows "Completed" and "Cancelled" orders.
- Each tab component is taking the `orders` state and using `if` condition only shows the particular orders that should come under it.

Suppose, an action happens on server-side & an order goes from "Open" to "In Progress" status.

**Expected Behavior:**

Now, the user swipes down and refreshes the tab component. On refresh, it should fetch the orders updated data from the server and update the redux `orders` state. As soon as the `orders` state updates, all tabs data should be updated automatically.

**Actual Behavior:**

The user swipes down and refreshes the tab component. On refresh, it fetches the orders updated data from the server and updates the redux `orders` state. But after updating the state, the component view doesn't update appropriately. I mean, some part updates but some part doesn't update.

I guess, I am not updating the state properly in reducer. Following is the reducer code to GET and PUT the orders payload.

```
const orders = (state = {}, action)=> {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'GET_ORDERS':
      return action.payload
    case 'PUT_ORDERS':{
      let newState = state;
      if(action.payload != undefined){
        action.payload.map(function(order, index){
          if(newState[order.id] != undefined) {
            newState[order.id].order_status = order.order_status;
          } else {
            newState[order.id] = order;
          }
        });
      }
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload);
    }
  }
}
```

I am maintaining the key of the order object by assinging the order id as key. It's because, due to refresh if new order come, keys should not be reassigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating your orders rather than changing them into new objects. Even though your reducer state is producing new objects, if you have components tied to the order objects, they won't see these as changes. For example, if you have:

```
const { connect } = require('react-redux');

export function Order({ orderId, order }) {
  return (
    <div className="order">
      <span className="order-id">{order.id}</span>
      <span className="order-status">{order.order_status}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ orders }, { orderId }) => ({
  order: orders[orderId]
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Order);
```

...then the `order` prop that's passed to your component will be identified as the same object, and your component won't update.

Try changing your reducer as follows:

```
const orders = (state = {}, action)=> {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'GET_ORDERS':
      return action.payload
    case 'PUT_ORDERS': {
      const updates = action.payload.map((payloadOrder, index) => {
        const oldOrder = state[payloadOrder.id];
        const newOrder = oldOrder 
          ? { ...oldOrder, order_status: payloadOrder.order_status }
          : payloadOrder;
        return {
          [payloadOrder.id]: newOrder
        };
      });
      return Object.assign({}, state, ...updates);
    }
  }
}
```

With this change, every order object in your state that has been modified is a new object.

Comment: I put this code in my reducer and displaying it in a simple component. But still it's not updating the component on first fetch also. It displays blank screen. 
It shows the updated state only in console log after the PUT operation.
Can you please verify the reducer code if any mutation is still happening in it in first fetch scenario?

Comment: The issue is resolved. 
Actually, I was assigning the redux state to a local state and displaying the local state. But after omitting this assignment step and directly using the redux state as props, it worked.
Thanks.